# Allow only integers in TextBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm having a problem with checking textboxes and making sure there's only integers in them.

So far I'm able to confirm that there's text in the textboxes, but checking if they're integers isn't working.  Here's my code that so far works.

```
if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "need Cost of Disks");
    return;
}
if (textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
{
    errorProvider2.SetError(textBox2, "need Total disks in package");
    return;
}
if (textBox3.Text.Length == 0)
{
    errorProvider3.SetError(textBox3, "need the Gigabyte per disk");
    return;
}
try
{
    Double[] myValues = new Double[3];
    myValues[0] = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    myValues[1] = Double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    myValues[2] = Double.Parse(textBox3.Text);

    Double ppd = myValues[0] / myValues[1] / myValues[2];

    ppd = Math.Round(ppd, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    label4.Text = ppd.ToString();
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    //errorProvider1.SetError(label4, "testing1");

    //errorProvider2.SetError(label4, "testing2");

    //errorProvider3.SetError(label4, "testing3");
    return;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using regular expressions. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93804/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-C-NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your current pattern, something like this:

```
int tester;
if (!Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tester))
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "must be integer");
    return;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help.  had to change int to double but it worked after.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkx4h3az.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Override the [`Validating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) event in your form's textboxes and then you can do a [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) on the contents.

```
public void textBox1_Validating(...)
{
  // TryParse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the int.TryParse method to check if the string is an integer:

```
int n = 0;
bool isNumber = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out n);

if (!isNumber)
   return;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to permit ANYTHING except numbers into the editbox, hook into keyboard events, check for characters that aren't digits and cancel them out.

When you sort out what events are needed on one textbox, just reuse same event on others, since you don't have to copy events around.

Answer (score -1):

If you ever start using ajax tool kit, keep this for your records

```
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" TargetControlID="FUND_CD" FilterType="Custom" ValidChars="1234567890" runat="server">
                        </ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

Comment: What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: for some reason the rest of the post doesnt show, i included a code.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realize there was more in your post. But then again, if you looked closely at the question, it's about WinForms, not ASP.net so this wouldn't be very helpful to the question.