# Only allow digits in textbox C#

Tags: c#, textbox, digits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I allow only 0 or 1 to be entered in a TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882369/how-can-i-allow-only-0-or-1-to-be-entered-in-a-textbox)
>   [Allow only integers in TextBoxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656217/allow-only-integers-in-textboxes)

I'm working on a program now and I have a few simple `textboxes`. I keep getting an error when the input of the `textbox` is NOT a number, because it tries to convert it to a integer.

The code is very basic:

```
    int optelNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a digit."); //if optelNumber is not a digit
```

for example:

```
input in textbox = "Hello !" => pops up the Mess.Box
input in textbox = 123245 => keep running the program
```

Hope this is enough information. I've searched almost all other topics but all the code was to advanced for me. :(
Thanks for your time

- edit :

The `messagebox` is to catch the error and keep the program from crashing.

- edit :

  ```
  int vedett = 0, duvel = 0, kDuvel = 0, kriek = 0, pils = 0;

  //only digits allowed here
  int optelNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

  switch(comboItem)
  {
  case "vedett":
    vedett += optelNumber;
    break;
  case "duvel":
    duvel += optelNumber;
    break;
  case "kl. duvel":
    kDuvel += optelNumber;
    break;
  case "pils":
    pils += optelNumber;
    break;
  case "kriek":
    kriek += optelNumber;
    break;
  case "":
    MessageBox.Show("Kies een andere drank.");
    break;
  }
  ```

Comment: I don't know if this is want you need, but may help http://blog.csharphelper.com/2012/11/20/throw-standard-exceptions-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a `int.TryPase`

```
    int result;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out result))
      int optelNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
```

or

```
int result;
int optelNumber; 
        if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out result))
          optelNumber  = result;
```

Comment: What's the reason for using `Convert.ToInt32` again? result has the value..?

Comment: `ConvertToInt32`  calls `int.Parse` implicitely. But if the string is null `int.Parse` throws an exception whereas `Convert.ToInt32` returns 0.

Comment: edited for better coding practices.  Either one should work though

Comment: Doesn't really work no :s its probably me, ill add the rest of the code to make it mroe clearly

Comment: @DJBurb I've just never seen it used that way..

Comment: DjBurb, It worked for me, I just had to figure out what  
        if (int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out result)) Did. Thanks so much !

Comment: @LewsTherin: Why did you remove your answer?

Comment: @Patrick Hey, I dunno.. DjBurb has it right :P Although, I still don't see the point of the 1st method :O

Comment: @LewsTherin: But your answer was cleaner. I don't get the first method in this answer either. I don't see the "better coding practices" either.

Comment: @Patrick Lol, neither do I. I will do some reading later to see if I did miss anything.. either way it seems the OP has it figured out though ;)

Comment: Nick, if this answer helped can you accept it?